# Intellij Darcula - can I make the highglight colours and stripe marks wildly bright?

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

I'm having so many difficulties with intellij darcula. While I love the dark background/white foreground and the usual colours for methods/classes et al, highlights - for anything from search results to "identifier under caret" are *way* too dark. Like, you have to scan the page to see what the heck is highlighted.

I've changed several settings - search results/search results, the aforementioned "identifier under caret" and the "(write)" versions as well, but I still have problems.

To whit, double-clicking a variable makes it super dark, and clicking on a variable and then hitting "ctrl f" - the results across the page are still super dark.

Is there some sort of modified darcula with "search reuslts are distractingly bright" or some other settings I'm missing to fix this?

This is good, I click a variable:
[image: good, this is what I want, it's bright and easily visible on page]

This is bad, I double-clicked the variable. 
[image: bad, this occurs if I double-click the variable]

This is rubbish. I hit ctrl-f and now the variable disappears. 
[image: rubbish, if i click the variable then ctrl-f i get this]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the color of selected text:

1. Open "Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General"
2. "Editor | Selection foreground"
3. Apply "Foreground" color

[image]